# Position of Layout on canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, spannablestring

I am trying to draw a layout on the canvas.

First I create a layout with a spannable string inside the onLayout()

```
dynamicLayout = new DynamicLayout(spannableString, textPaint, mWidthPix, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 0.0f, 0.0f, false);
```

mWidthPix is the width of the mobile device.

Now I draw this layout in the canvas using the following code :

```
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(0,paddingTop);
dynamicLayout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

I need the string to be centrally aligned and displayed on the screen. But that does not happen. The string position changes when I run the code on different devices.

Also a part of the spannable string needs to be of a different color. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: horizontally center.

Comment: use proper Layout.Alignment then